# Access 2010 query data type mismatch

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, type-mismatch

I got `query2` on `query1`, in `query1` there is a expression where the result is either `"yes"` or `"no"`:

```
expr1:IIf(DateSeriel(Year([date1])+[runtime];Month([date1])+[runtime2];Day([date1]))>Da‌​te();"yes";"no")
```

The result is fine but the where clause on query2 now produces a data type mismatch

```
SELECT tbl1.customer 
FROM query1
WHERE (query1.[expr1]="yes");
```

`'yes'` or changing it to `TRUE`/`FALSE` isnt working either. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Syntax error, unmatching `)` at the end.

Comment: you are right, fixed it. problem still applies

Comment: try to include query 1 as well.

Comment: You need to include your first query, so that we can see what does it output, else we will be just guessing.

Comment: returns the correct value "no"

Comment: have you tried 0 and 1, numbers tend to be somewhat easier to work with than strings.

Comment: 0 and 1 returns the same error. do i have to somewhat format the expr1 into something? bc of the dateserial ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Answer to that particular problem but a workaround...
I did another temporary table with all the records that are filtered by the `expr1` and made the query on that table.